# ANOVA post-hoc correction question

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, bonferroni

I am currently analysing data from a recent experiment, in which I will perform a 2 way repeated measures ANOVA (exercise intensity [3 intensities] x time [5 time points]).

I have a significant intensity x time interaciton, and so I ran the post-hocs with Bonferonni corrections. However, because there is quite a high number of comparisons, the post-hocs often yield non-significant results, presumably due in part to the number of corrections. This is fine of course, but, many of the corrections are in some ways irrelvant.

For example, I am interested in the change in my dependent variable over time within a given exercise intensity (e.g. does intensity 1, 2 or 3 change over time), and I am interested in whether there are differences between the intensities at a given time-point (e.g. does intensity 1 differ from 2 and 3 at time point 1 for example). I am not interested in whether my dependent variable at intensity 1, time point 1 differs from intensity 3, time point 4 (hypothetical example), and yet these corrections are incorporated into the Bonferonni post-hoc p value. Should this be the case, or is there a way to remove the irrelevant pairwise comparisons so that they are not included in the corrections?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could define a custom of contrasts you are interested in and use it for comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, **some** method is needed to avoid 'false discovery'. Suppose you have 10 levels of a factor, so there are ${10\choose 2}=45$ possible paired comparisons. Suppose comparisons are independent and than none are truly significant (means really the same), but you test all 45 at the 5% level of significance,. Then there is probability $1 - .95^{45} \approx 0.9$ that at least one of them will show an erroneously significant result.

Because the Bonferroni method is based on an inequality, it does tend to be a little too
conservative (not likely enough to notice real differences) when many *ad hoc* comparisons are
made. So you should choose a 'penalty' that
matches the number of comparisons actually made.

However, one might conclude from your narrative
that you'd criticize *any method* of protecting against
false discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated measures ANOVA has been obsolete for more than two decades.  Use a method that respects the serial correlations in your data, e.g., generalized least squares (e.g., with an AR(1) correlation structure) or Markov models.

Comment: Can you recommend a textbook that covers Markov models?

Comment: Https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19 where you'll see several reports that describe the great versatility of the Markov approach especially when using a Bayesian approach.  See links to other papers there too.